# error:socket select() function always returning zero in iOS system

Tags: ios, sockets, select

can any one tell me why the following code most time return 0 . some time return 1. i test it in 3G network. that's make the player sometime play and sometime pause。I am confuse ?

```
fd_set  readSet;
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 250*1000;
FD_ZERO( &readSet );
FD_SET( http->fd, &readSet );
ret = select(http->fd + 1,&readSet,0,0,&tv);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set a timeout of 250 milliseconds on the read, so `select()` is returning when that timeout expires without any data being received. This is expected behavior, especially on a cellular connection which may be subject to high latency.

Allow me to suggest a better approach here. Use [CFSocket](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html) to wrap the file handle, then add that to your application's run loop as an event source. This will obviate the need for `select()` entirely.

Comment: in iOS, using sockets directly using POSIX functions or CFSocket does not automatically activate the device’s cellular modem or on-demand VPN. is there any difference between select() and CFSocket?